# attribute directive that adds element to the dom from a template file

Tags: angularjs

i have a template file myfile.html and i'm writing an attribute directive in angular, the purpose of this directive is to insert the elements that are inside myfile.html after the element that the directive attribute was declared on. for example:  will insert all the content of myfile.html after that div.

i tried to do it like so:

```js
app.directive('myAngularDirective', function () {
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    link: function(scope, element){
      var addMe = angular.element("myfile.html");
      element.after($copile(addMe));
      scope.$apply();
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<h1>myfile.html</h1>
<div ng-controller="myController">
  <div ng-click=clickMe()></div>
</div>
```

```html
<h1>my home page</h1>
<div my-angular-directive></div>
```

but nothing happens, the content of myfile.html is not added to the home page.

if i write plain html in the after function like so:
element.after("")

it does get added to the dom but angular do not digest it, and ng-click is not working.

thanks for your help.

Comment: possible to create fiddle or plunker replicating this issue ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$compile("<html here>")` returns a template function that expects a scope to be passed before you get your DOM back. Change your code to the following and it should work as expected:

```
app.directive('myAngularDirective', function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    link: function(scope, element){
      var addMe = angular.element("<div>Hello World</div>");
      element.after($compile(addMe)(scope));
      scope.$apply();
    }
  }
});
```

If you want to load the template from an external URL. You'll need to do a template request.

```
app.directive('myAngularDirective', function($compile,$templateRequest) {
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    link: function(scope, element){
      $templateRequest('index.html').then(function(tpl){
        var addMe = angular.element(tpl);
        element.after($compile(addMe)(scope));
        scope.$apply();
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: do neither the templateUrl, nor template ddo attributes work for 'Attribute' directive definition objects? Or is $templateRequest the only way?